# Query TypeError: snackbarContainer is null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this error in my browser:

> TypeError: snackbarContainer is null

If I click on my button, there is no action, just the browser error in my developer tool:

```
 <a onclick="buildAPK();"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">APK Generieren</button></a>
```

**js code:**

```
function buildAPK(){
    $.post("build/build_apk.php", {    
        cmd: "build",
        icon: $("#icon_for_build").val(),
        packname: $("#packname_for_build").val(),
        seller: $("#seller_for_build").val(),
        appname: $("#appname_for_build").val(),
        time: $("#time_for_build").val(),
        ptitle: $("#ptitle_for_build").val(),
        ptext: $("#ptext_for_build").val(),
        ptime: $("#ptime_for_build").val(),
        domain1: $("#domain1_for_build").val(),
        domain2: $("#domain2_for_build").val(),
        domain3: $("#domain3_for_build").val(),
        domain4: $("#domain4_for_build").val(),
        domain5: $("#domain5_for_build").val(),
        welcomepage: $("#welcompage_for_build").val()
    },
    function(data, status){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

         //alert(obj.message);
         var snackbarContainer = document.querySelector('#demo-toast-example');
         var show_data = {message: obj.message};
         snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(show_data);
    });
}
```

Whats wrong with my code? Does anyone have an idea?

Full browser error:

> TypeError: snackbarContainer is null[Learn More] scripts.js:785:4
>   buildAPK/< ............../js/scripts.js:785:4 i
>   ............../js/vendor.bundle.base.js:2:28012
>   fireWith
>   ............../js/vendor.bundle.base.js:2:28783
>   A
>   ............../js/vendor.bundle.base.js:4:14033
>   c/<
>   ............../js/vendor.bundle.base.js:4:16323
>
> Source map error: request failed with status 404 Resource URL:
>   ............../js/vendor.bundle.base.js Source
>   Map URL: bootstrap.min.js.map[Learn More]

**#demo-toast-example exist in my Index Page**

Url: `/index.php?command=build`

The first Button (buildAPK) is in the code from `command=build` file.

**index.php**

```
 <div id="demo-toast-example" class="mdl-js-snackbar mdl-snackbar">
      <div class="mdl-snackbar__text"></div>
      <button class="mdl-snackbar__action" type="button"></button>
    </div>
```

Comment: It seems document.querySelector('#demo-toast-example')  is not present in your scaffolding

Comment: Full Error code Updated.

Comment: Yeah, so that's pretty self explanitory.  The variable is null.  So it's not being found by the selector you're using.

Comment: Can i bypass it or remove #demo-toast-example ? Or whats the solution for it:)

Comment: does `demo-toast-example` exist? You havent included it in your code.

Comment: Not in the Script from button. I think i dont need it for my Button

Comment: does it exist on the page before you call your function?

Comment: Its exist in my Index Page, Updated.

Comment: Where is your javascript loaded? Index page? Head, or body, do you wait for the page to load before your JavaScript?

Comment: JS loaded in Index.php Header.

Comment: You should load your JS at the bottom of the page just before the body closing tag. This ensures that the whole page has loaded before your JS is called. By the sounds of things your JS is running before the page has fully loaded so that the `demo-toast-example` doesnt exist. Or if youre using jquery wrap your JavaScript with `$( document ).ready(function() { ..... your code here..... });

Comment: Found the error:) i am an idiot :D  i had opened the old index file where demo-toast-example not exist.. Thanks all for help:)

Comment: Ha. Been there. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Thanks for your great help and time:)